# How to stop python from printing commas from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

whenever I print the contents of a csv file it prints the commas. Is there a way of printing it without commas.

This is how I am reading the text file.

```
     f = open(class_name + ".csv", 'rt')
     file_ = f.read()
     print (file_)
     f.close()
```

It prints like this

Ardrito : ,5

But I want it to print like this

Ardrito : 5

Comment: Please show how the input file looks like. Right now you print the file exactly as it is on disk, so those commas are in your input file. If you want to parse the file then you should parse it, but right now it's unclear to me what your goal is.

Comment: Have you tried googling "python csv"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're after...

```
with open(class_name + ".csv", 'rt') as f:
  for line in f:
    print line.strip().replace(',', ' ')
```

Alternatively, there's a module called `csv` that may be useful to you.

Comment: This really helped thanks. Just if some one is going to do this in IDLE 3.5 remember the brackets when printing.

Comment: @Ardrito: That's one of the differences from Python 2 to Python 3.

Comment: @Ardrito It's going through each line of the file and printing the output. Have you tried running it?

Comment: @Matthias: yes sorry there was a line in my code which should not have been there, it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `csv.reader` object to read your file. See the Python documentation for the csv module for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting the file the same way as it is on disk. If you want to parse the file you should check out the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) of Python.